# SSRS Double Hop Authentication?

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I have created reports on SQL 2008 R2 Server and deployed the reports and data source to the same server. The data source uses a database residing on a SQL 2005 server. Also looking to use Windows Integrated security.

Similar to many other posts - when trying to run the reports on workstations or servers (other than the 2008-R2 server that also has the reporting services) I get the error:
An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
Cannot create a connection to data source 'MemberFeeDetails'. (rsErrorOpeningConnection)
Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.

Q:Would this scenario be considered a Two Hop Authentication issue and thus require the Kerberos Authentication? If that is the case, then I will look to set up the Kerberos Authentication. All comments are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

If the database server where the SSRS databases are hosted is a different server than the one where you installed SSRS, then yes, this is a double-hop issue. 100%

Answer (score 0):

Another way to handle this scenario is to setup a sql user on your database server. Give the sql user limited access to view the data only in the tables or database where the report(s) data resides.

This allows any of your reports to connect via the sql user and you secure the report by using the ssrs administration portal, adding only the necessary windows users to the reports. A benefit of this is you do not have to keep adding windows users to sql server to access the data etc.